# TimeoutException while creating new app in Typesafe Activator Commandline

Tags: scala, command-line, fedora, playframework-2.2, typesafe-activator

Every time i'm getting following error when i try to create new app using typesafe activator command line.By Activator UI its working normal & m using Typesafe Activator 1.0.10 in Fedora20.

```
Enter an application name
> hello-scala
Futures timed out after [6 seconds]
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [6 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:100)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcI$sp(ActivatorCli.scala:32)
    at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:17)
    at activator.ActivatorCli$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:17)
    at activator.ActivatorCli$.withContextClassloader(ActivatorCli.scala:127)
    at activator.ActivatorCli$.apply(ActivatorCli.scala:17)
    at activator.ActivatorLauncher.run(ActivatorLauncher.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:77)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:57)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Comment: This is when it goes to fetch the template repository.  Do you have a proxy server or have you put any proxy settings in your `.activator/activatorconfig.txt` file?

Comment: What is strange is that the UI and the CLI should be doing the same thing.  I'll look into this further.  In the meantime can you file a bug? https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved with the latest Activator: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/225

Download it: http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted